# SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\helloworldspring.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, tomcat8

I am facing a problem when running my code. Every time I run my code this error is thrown by the server, I checked every jar I added correct also checked `jdk` and `jre` path but I'm unable to solve the issue.

> Aug 07, 2017 2:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
>       SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\helloworldspring.xml
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/helloworldspring]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Aug 07, 2017 2:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.myspring.controller"></context:component-scan>
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>

        <bean id ="viewResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefiex" value = "/WEB-INF/pages"></property>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

and web.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>helloworldspring</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what is the *underlying* error you get?

Comment: post complete logs. also show your helloworldspring.xml and if possible project structure

Comment: i create simple dynamic web project and my file are like : i added my xml file  code

Answer (score 0):

Check the exception in detail, especially the "Caused by" part. It definitely helps you to find the cause.

Also if you are using maven, check the maven dependency tree if there are any jar files with different version, especially **servlet jar**.

Add "-verbose to the list of JVM_OPTS in tomcat "bin/wrapper.conf" if on windows
**wrapper.java.additional.11="-verbose"**. This will help you to find the root cause

Comment: i am using eclipse oxygen java 1.8 with tomcat 8.045 every time i facing problem above mentioned and 404 error @ the time of execute my program

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem like ,

```
14-May-2018 19:12:40.190 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /home/chandrakant/apache-tomcat-8.0.48/conf/Catalina/localhost/sbic.xml
14-May-2018 19:12:40.192 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sbic]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@55c9a2a4]
```

and i have solve it out by removing all xml file from apache/conf/Catalina/localhost except web.xml and it working fine.